# Adding the source code to eclipse does not showing .java files

Tags: java, eclipse

I have attached the source code of rt.jar file ie src.zip to my Eclipse.

My problem is that, After adding the source code of rt.jar to eclipse, when I open any class,for Example "String" class, The eclipse itself showing ".class" file for "String" only,It does nopt showing ".java" file for "String".

How can I see the ".java" file?

Comment: I think showing .class is fine. However the .class file should have the source attachment, and it should show the source code contents.

Answer (score 0):

The source file is exactly that, the source file. You are reading the files in the .jar. Adding the source is not a magical way in which you can edit the .jar. If you could change the underlying Java source code it would be one of the biggest security risks. The .class file is a representation of the .java file and as such there is also no reason for you to need the .java file.

Comment: Can I debug in the .class file.

Comment: No but you could create a test class that calls the class and debug like that. Again you would be debugging the Java source, so unless you found a bug and want to submit it to Oracle, you probably better off checking your own code if you are running into trouble.

Comment: So finally .class file is only visible but not .java file if we attach source code right.

Comment: Is it possible to view the .java file in eclipse?

Comment: No but you could copy the contents of the .class file into your own .java file.

Comment: k.When we debug that class file with our test class,can we see the variable values in that .class file?

Comment: Yes if you use the debugger and go into say String.equalTo(Object o) method you will see the .class file and var values.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to attach the source code, as shown in the below screen shot.

[image]